# Read binary file in C# from specific position

Tags: c#, binary-data

Is it possible to read a large binary file from a particular position?

I don't want to read the file from the beginning because I can calculate the start position and the length of the stream I need.

Comment: All you have to do is change the `Position` property, or use the `Seek` method. Are you worried that the entire file is loaded into memory?

Comment: Yes, I dont want to load the entire file into memory. I use the BinaryReader and couldnt find the Seek method. --> BinaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(), thats the solution. ;-)

Comment: You won't have to worry about a huge file being loaded into memory. A stream only loads a portion of it at a time. Otherwise we would never be able to open huge files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
using (FileStream sr = File.OpenRead("someFile.dat"))
{
    sr.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    int read = sr.ReadByte();
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

According to *@shenhengbin* answord.

Use `BinaryReader.BaseStream.Seek`.

```
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("perls.bin", FileMode.Open)))                                                     
{
    int pos = 50000;
    int required = 2000;

    // Seek to our required position.
    b.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Read the next 2000 bytes.
    byte[] by = b.ReadBytes(required);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you know streams, why not using (File)Stream.Seek(...) ?

Comment: I use the BinaryStream but I couldnt find the Seek() method. The link from Scott explains how to get the seek method on a binary reader. 
BinaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.See this [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html).See the offset.you can read from the offset

Comment: Not really, the offset defines the offset for the buffer not for the starting point of the file. I tried this way before I wrote this entry.